# Is there any other reason why NULL is not allowed in ArrayDeque besides "null is used as a special return value"?

Tags: java, null, queue

Before you try to find duplicate question or downvotes, please let me explain :)

I think I read most of **stackoverflow** answers on this topic. They all summarize to this:

> Null should not be inserted into a Queue, as null is also used as a
> special return value by some methods to indicate that the queue
> contains no elements.

They are totally right (let's ignore `LinkedList` here). If I were to call for example `queue.poll()` or `queue.peek()` and return type is *null*, I wouldn't know if that *null* **represents *null* as element** or ***null* as no elements**.

But any programmer with basic knowledge can do something like this to avoid given problem:

```
            //queue initialization..            
            queue.add(null);
            if (!queue.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println(queue.poll());
            }
```

So I must ask again. Was "*null* as special return type" only reason why it is 'banned' in mostly `Queue` implementations(except `LinkedList`)? Or I am missing something additional concerning this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queue implementations could have been designed to permit null entries, but they were not.   This is a design tradeoff:  the 'flexibility' of being able to insert null entries, versus the cumbersome programming interface of having to check whether the queue contains any elements before you can call a method that is there in part to determine whether the queue contains any elements.

The clue is in the name 'poll'.  If poll is not able to perform a 'remove and return; else indicate nothing to return', then poll is not a useful method; a test for empty, followed by the existing 'remove' call, does the job.

I suppose, therefore, that the queue designers had in mind a queue that contained 'things' rather than the absence of things (i.e., they took the word literally) and accepted that restriction for the convenience of a single-method poll call.

In short, your answer (IMO) is 'yes, that is the reason', but I think the reason is a good one.

Comment: I like the answer, but yet List was not designed that way, and it has almost the same functionality . There they didn't stick with "contained things rather than the absence of things".. I know this is rather personal question, but why does List even have nulls then?

Comment: All I can say is, there are very different semantics associated with 'queue' and 'list', even if there are data structures that can be used for either. From doc for queue: *A collection designed for holding elements prior to processing.*, and for List: *An ordered collection (also known as a sequence). … The user can access elements by their integer index*   The interfaces are designed to fulfil different needs. As for why List permits nulls: because absent the need for a poll method, there's no reason to prohibit nulls. 'Polling' is not a concept that really goes with 'list'.